# Как скрыть поля в профиле пользователя только для определенных групп пользователей? Bitrix

Tags: php, битрикс

Есть определенные роли у пользователей (администраторы группы N) которые могут редактировать профиль любого пользователя, а точнее личную информацию и проставлять галочки квалификации в чекбоксы. Есть администраторы группы T которые могут делать тоже самое, но не могут проставлять галочки квалификации в профиле любого пользователя. Как сделать такой фильтр по группам?
Код определения принадлежности текущего пользователя накатал, а как и где это работает должно - не знаю.

```js
if ( CSite::InGroup( array(10) ) ):
echo "Ура";
endif;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: о какой редакции битрикса идет речь?

Comment: @Igor Битрикс: Управление сайтом

Comment: Права и роли задавались для модуля, значит нужно смотреть по нему, какие шаблоны использует.

Comment: @Igor спасибо посмотрю!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример у меня

```
$groups_arr = $USER->GetUserGroupArray();
if(!in_array(9,$groups_arr)) die('Ваш аккаунт не принадлежит группе NAME');
```

У вас должно быть, примерно так:

```
$groups_arr = $USER->GetUserGroupArray();
if (in_array(10,$groups_arr)):
    echo "Ура";
endif;
```

Можно добавить в шаблон профиля